# Calling ROS services in Python using yaml notation for the parameters?

Tags: ros, python, yaml, rosservice

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everybody!
I was wondering if it was possible to call a ROS service from within a python node using YAML notation for the parameters like the console tool *rosservice*. Something like:

```
rosservice call /add_two_ints '{a:1, b:2}'
```

But from within a python node:

```
add_two_ints = rospy.ServiceProxy( 'add_two_ints', AddTwoInts )
add_two_ints( "{a:1, b:2}" )
```

I already know that the following is possible, but it's not what I'm looking for:

```
add_two_ints( a=1, b=2 )
```

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10854/calling-ros-services-in-python-using-yaml-notation-for-the-parameters?/) by [pparescasellas](https://answers.ros.org/users/693/pparescasellas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2011-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, but the Python yaml module is very easy to use and will convert the yaml notation into a form suitable for Python.

```
In [5]: yaml.load("{a: 1, b: 2}")
Out[5]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

similarly, the add_two_ints( a=1, b=2 ) form is equivalent to

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
add_two_int(**d)
```

NOTE: the keyword-form is not recursive

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-08-10**:
You can look at the source code for rosservice, which is in Python.

**Comment by [pparescasellas](https://answers.ros.org/users/693/pparescasellas/) on 2011-08-10**:
Is it possible to call the service without specifying the service message name? I'm trying to do a generic service caller and that's why I wanted to send parameters in yaml-format. I'd like to be able to call any service by just knowking the service name and the yaml parameters

**Comment by [pparescasellas](https://answers.ros.org/users/693/pparescasellas/) on 2011-08-10**:
Oh great! I'll give it a try, thanks ;)